# Index Out of Range on Tuple Integer Converted To String

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to print the last digit of an integer that's been pulled from a database and converted to a string. normally, this code works fine to print the last character of a string even if its a number thats been coverted to a string:

```
x = 225
print x[-1]
5
```

However, when I try to do the same thing on a value thats been pulled from a database, the Python interpreter gives me a string index out of range error.

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb

#mysql card_numbercheck
class NumberCheck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='mscan')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, arg, cardname):
        self.c.execute(arg, cardname)
        return self.c

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

# Define SQL statement to select all Data from Column Name
sql = "SELECT card_number FROM inventory_2 WHERE card_name = %s"

#Connect To DB and Get Number of Card. 
def Get_MTG_Number():
    global card_number
    MtgNumber = NumberCheck()
    for number in MtgNumber.query(sql, 'Anathemancer'):
        card_number = str(number[0])

    print card_number[-1]
```

Get_MTG_Number()

Logically, I don't really understand why this code wouldn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the data fields are blank, and by converting to a string you are just getting an empty string? Trying to index such a string will give you an 'index out of range' error.

To see what is going on, you could simply print card_number upon each iteration of the loop. You could also do with a bit more error handling to sanitize the data you are getting from a database.